# Not able to drag a formula calculating days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which gives me the day ie Monday , Tuesday etc. But the problem i am having is that i am not able drag the formula to give me the next day.

I am trying to drag this along the row.

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(CurrentYear,1,1),1),"aaa")
```

So if i drag i should get the below formulea which i am not getting.

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(CurrentYear,1,2),1),"aaa")
```

Therefore the next formula will have a 2 in the formula , and then the next will have 3 in the formula and so.

Comment: Depending on which way you are dragging, add a `ROWS` or `COLUMNS` function instead of the literal value.

Comment: off topic but `WEEKDAY` function is redundant here, in fact depending on date system used it could give you an incorrect result - use just `=TEXT(DATE(CurrentYear,1,1),"aaa")`

Comment: @Rory - Hey! how's it going?

Comment: @barryhoudini Busy (obviously!). Nice to see you back out in the interweb!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dragging only updates cell references not numbers. You need to write your formula to reference a cell location in some way. Try

=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(CurrentYear,1,Column(a1)),1),"aaa")

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set up a static index of 1-7 and make the formula refer to that - this will make the reference update as you drag it along the columns:

So, per this example:

[image]

The formula is:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(CurrentYear,1,E$1),1),"aaa")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this formula

`=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(2017,1,1)),"ddd")`

then you are not actually finding the day of `1/1/2017` because `=WEEKDAY(DATE(2017,1,1)` resolves to the number 1 and then `TEXT` function finds the weekday of the date represented by 1 in Excel - this can be two different dates, normally 1/1/1900, but if you use 1904 date system (which used to be common on Macs) then that date is 2nd Jan 1904. While 1/1/1900 was a Sunday (according to Excel) the 2nd Jan 1904 was a Saturday so your result might be incorrect.

`WEEKDAY` function here is at best redundant, or worst it results in an incorrect result, so should be removed

To answer your query it's best to use `COLUMNS` function, rather than `COLUMN` (as per Rory's suggestion in comments), because then adding or deleting columns or rows won't affect the result, so final formula, to be dragged **across**, should be similar to this:

`=TEXT(DATE(CurrentYear,1,COLUMNS($B3:B3)),"ddd")`

Where `B3` is the first cell with the formula - change as required

`1904 Date System` setting is workbook level setting than can be altered through `Options` > `Advanced`